# Fill the width in landscape mode with two imageviews

Tags: java, android, imageview, landscape

I have this recyclerview, and the background is made with imageviews. I have these two situations in portrait and landscape. How do I fill the white space there with a new imageview or something with the same color?

[image: portrait][image: landscape]

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home_imageview_superbackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home_imageview_background"
    android:contentDescription="Background image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tried several ways, but I'm just not able to make this work. @+id/home_imageview_superbackground this is the imageview I want to put on the left of each background imageview to fill that space in the landscape. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_imageview_superbackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_imageview_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="Background image" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use  android:scaleType="centerCrop".

Hope this will help you..If still you face problem please inform me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 .... />
```

Also you can use `scaleType`attribute

Comment: i'm sorry mate but you're not even trying to help me :)

Comment: Sorry. Create a land-scape variation layout.

Answer (score 0):

First, the *fill_parent* is deprecated times ago, you should use *match_parent* instead. Then, you have also to use scaleType when you're working with ImagesView to define how the image looks on the screen. In your case, working with scaleType = "fitXY" solve your problem.

How your code should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home_imageview_superbackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home_imageview_background"
    android:contentDescription="Background image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, i'll modify all of my fill_parent with match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_gradiant"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Hello Three"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And create this drawable file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <gradient android:angle="0"
             android:startColor="#64FFDA"
             android:centerColor="#4464FFDA"
             android:endColor="#0064FFDA"/>
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```